# ¿How to prove $\{(1,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ is the basis of $\{(x,x,y) \in F^3: x,y \in F\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

The title comes from an example found in Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right". Section 2.B, Bases, Example 2.28 E).

I am at a loss at how to approach the problem.

Would it be correct to state something like $$x\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix} + y\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x\\x\\y\end{bmatrix}?$$

I mean, is that enough or it lacks something else?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to prove they are linearly independent to complete the proof.

Comment: @123 Alright. Thanks!

Comment: What you have done so far shows that your candidate for a basis indeed spans the set of the given vectors. Now show that your candidate does not have anything redundant, i.e. linearly dependent vectors. In other words, show that your candidate is a linearly independent set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\textbf{(i)}$ show that the set $\{(1,1,0),(1,1,0)\}$ span $\{(x,x,y) \in F^3: x,y \in F\}=K$. It means that for all $(x,x,y)\in K$ we can find $c_1$ and $c_2$ in $F$ such that  $(x,x,y)=c_1(1,1,0)+c_2(0,0,1)$.

$\textbf{(ii)}$ You must show that two vectors $(1,1,0)$ and $(1,1,0)$ are linearly independent. It means that for $c_1, c_2\in F$ if  $c_1(1,1,0)+c_2(0,0,1)=0$, then $c_1=c_2=0$.
Your solution just first step.